# A regex that doesn't match with this character sequence

Tags: java, regex

Here is my Regex, I am trying to search all special characters so that I can escape them.

```
(\(|\)|\[|\]|\{|\}|\?|\+|\\|\.|\$|\^|\*|\||\!|\&|\-|\@|\#|\%|\_|\"|\:|\<|\>|\/|\;|\'|\`|\~)
```

My problem here is, I don't want to escape some sepcial characters only when the come in a sequence

like this `(.*)`

So, Lets consider an example.

```
Sting message = "Hi, Mr.Xyz! Your account number is :- (1234567890) , (,*) &$@%#*(....))(((";
```

After escaping according to current regex what i get is,

```
Hi, Mr\.Xyz\! Your account number is \:\- \(1234567890\) , \(,\*\) \&\$\@\%\#\*\(\.\.\.\.\)\)\(\(\(
```

But is don't want to escape this part `(.*)` want to keep it as it is.

My above regex is only used for searching, So i just don't want to match with this part `(.*)` and my problem will be solved

Can anyone suggest regex that doesn't escape that part of the string?

Comment: There is no such part in the string that I can see.

Comment: You should really consider using `[character classes]` instead of `a|l|t|e|r|n|a|t|i|o|n`

Comment: @izomorphius, I am talking about this character sequence `(.*)` I don't want to match with it.

Comment: The sequence `(.*)` does not exist within your regex input.

Comment: Any chance you could split this task into several steps instead of conjuring up some insanely complex regex? How about finding all (.*) first and replace them with something alphabetical, and then do the reverse on the escaped string?

Comment: @ Telthien,Thats true, I am trying to understand how to add the same so that its doesn't match when encountered

Comment: That task is beyond the capability of regular expressions.  Without a COMPLETE problem specification it will be hard to help you, i.e. is `(.*)` the only sequence that shouldn't be escaped.  What you seem to want is to escape special characters in an arbitrary string while also detecting regexes embedded in the string.  That task requires manual intervention as there are no rules that can disambiguate all possible scenarios.

Comment: Why use a regex which will probably be complicated if you can simply just loop through the string, checking character by character if it is on your special-character list and the next one is not? It will probably run faster too. Regexes look elegant because they can be written tersely. However, in the background, they have to be compiled at runtime, and executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This answer is to demonstrate the possibility only. Using it in production code is questionable.**

It is possible with Java String `replaceAll` function:

```
String input = "Hi, Mr.Xyz! Your account number is :- (1234567890) , (.*) &$@%#*(....))(((";
String output = input.replaceAll("\\G((?:[^()\\[\\]{}?+\\\\.$^*|!&@#%_\":<>/;'`~-]|\\Q(.*)\\E)*+)([()\\[\\]{}?+\\\\.$^*|!&@#%_\":<>/;'`~-])", "$1\\\\$2");
```

Result:

```
"Hi, Mr\.Xyz\! Your account number is \:\- \(1234567890\) , (.*) \&\$\@\%\#\*\(\.\.\.\.\)\)\(\(\("
```

Another test:

```
String input = "(.*) sdfHi test message <> >>>>><<<<f<f<,,,,<> <>(.*) sdf (.*)  sdf (.*)";
```

Result:

```
"(.*) sdfHi test message \<\> \>\>\>\>\>\<\<\<\<f\<f\<,,,,\<\> \<\>(.*) sdf (.*)  sdf (.*)"
```

---

**Explanation**

Raw regex:

```
\G((?:[^()\[\]{}?+\\.$^*|!&@#%_":<>/;'`~-]|\Q(.*)\E)*+)([()\[\]{}?+\\.$^*|!&@#%_":<>/;'`~-])
```

Note that `\` is escaped once more when the regex is specified inside the string, and `"` needs to be escaped. The resulting regex in string can be seen above.

Raw replacement string:

```
$1\\$2
```

Since `$` has special meaning in replacement string, and you want to **keep** it for `$2`, you need to escape the `\` so that `\` won't escape the `$`. And putting the replacement string in quoted string, you need to double up the number of `\` to escape the `\`.

Before we dissect the monster, let's talk about the idea. We will consume non-special characters, and the sequence that we don't want to replace, and as many times as possible. The next character will either be a special character not forming sequence we don't want to replace, or is the end of the string (which means that we have found all character that needs replacing if any).

Naturally, we can think of any arbitrary string as consisting of many of the following pattern consecutively: `[0 or more (non-special character or special pattern not to be replace)][special character]`, and the string ends with `[0 or more (non-special character or special pattern not to be replace)]`.

`replaceAll` function when used with a regex without `\G` may find matches that are not consecutive, which can cut in the middle of the sequence not to be replaced and mess it up. `\G` means the boundary of last match, and can be used to make sure the next match starts from where the last match left off.

- `\G`: Starts from last match
- `` ((?:[^()\[\]{}?+\\.$^*|!&@#%_":<>/;'`~-]|\Q(.\*)\E)*+) ``: Capture 0 or more of, the non-special character or the special pattern not to be replaced. Note that I have added the possessive qualifier `+` after `*`. This will prevent the engine from backtracking when it cannot find the special character that we specify after this.

  - `` [^()\[\]{}?+\\.$^*|!&@#%_":<>/;'`~-] ``: Negated character class of special characters.
  - `\Q(.*)\E`: Special sequence `(.*)` not to be replaced, literal quoted by `\Q` and `\E`.
- `` ([()\[\]{}?+\\.$^*|!&@#%_":<>/;'`~-]) ``: Capture the single special character.

The whole regex will match string with minimum length of 1 (the special character). The first capturing group contains the parts that shouldn't be replaced, and the 2nd capturing group contains the special character that should be replaced.

Comment: I am sure your solution is a better one! Thanks. It works for most cases. I found a situation where it doesn't work as designed. consider to replace this string with your regex `Hi test message <> >>>>><<<<<<,,,,<> <>` and you'll get the result as this `Hi test message (.*) \>\>\>\>\>\<\<\<\<\<\<,,,,(.*) \(\.\*\)`

Comment: @AvinashNair: Please see the edit. It's nice that I learn something from this mistake. Anyway, I think you should use fge's solution. It is much clearer than this bunch of regex.

Comment: Thanks for your help. You've helped me learn something new! you guys are incredible!

Answer (score 3):

See @nhahtdh for how to do this with a regex.

As an alternative, Here is a solution which does not use a regex, using Guava's [CharMatcher](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.html) instead:

```
private static final CharMatcher SPECIAL
    = CharMatcher.anyOf("allspecialcharshere");
private static final String NO_ESCAPE = "(.*)";

public String doEncode(String input)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(input.length());

    String tmp = input;

    while (!tmp.isEmpty()) {
        if (tmp.startsWith(NO_ESCAPE)) {
            sb.append(NO_ESCAPE);
            tmp = tmp.substring(NO_ESCAPE.length());
            continue;
        }
        char c = tmp.charAt(0);
        if (SPECIAL.matches(c))
            sb.append('\\');
        sb.append(c);
        tmp = tmp.substring(1);
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: I tried your regex, (?=[()\[\]{}?+\\.$^*|!&\-@#%_:<>/;'~])(?!\Q(.*)\E). But no help, it does match with `(.*)`

Comment: I want it to match with `(`, `)`, `.`, `*` individually but if this `(.*)` comes together in this sequence i don't want to match with it

Comment: It does work with my tests, so what you are saying is rather strange.

Comment: Hmm no, indeed, I have overlooked something. The CharMatcher version works, however.

Comment: @fge: Replacement part as code is equivalent to Matcher loop in Java.

Comment: @fge: It is possible, but kinda ugly. See my answer.

Comment: @nhahtdh well done! I guess I was too obsessed with the non negated character class...